# Removed php session in Jquery or Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Does anyone know whether I can removed a php session by using jquery or javascript?

Comment: do you mean the session in cookie??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Regular" cookies can be deleted in JavaScript using something along these lines:

This function will "delete" the supplied cookie from the browser by setting the cookie's expiry date to one second in the past.

```
function delete_cookie ( cookie_name )
{
  var cookie_date = new Date ( );  // current date & time
  cookie_date.setTime ( cookie_date.getTime() - 1 );
  document.cookie = cookie_name += "=; expires=" + cookie_date.toGMTString();
}
```

If the cookie is a httpOnly cookie (a cookie with the [httpOnly parameter](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/HTTPOnly) set), you cannot read, change or delete it without closing the session (i.e. close the browser).

Comment: In case the OP doesn't know, the session is stored server-side, but a cookie is stored client-side with the session id. Thus deleting this session id cookie will remove remove the session.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't look likely. JavaScript has access to client-side cookies. Session cookies are set from the server.

Answer (score 0):

jin  we can delete a cookie in a page through javascript , but again if you go to some other page it will be set again from the server,

you can do a session off from the server